# NSUserDefaults returns null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults, uilocalnotification

Can `UILocalNotification` be stored in `NSUserDefaults`?

I tried to get the value but it always returns null.

Here's the method that tries to get the value

```
-(IBAction)doneClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefx = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    UILocalNotification *oldNotifObj = [prefx objectForKey:@"NotificationObject"];
    NSLog(@"oldNotifObj = %@",oldNotifObj);

    NSLog(@"enable notification");
    if (oldNotifObj == nil)
    {
        [self addNotification];
        NSLog(@"add a new one");
    }
    else
    {
        //if notification exist, remove old one, and add new one.
        [self removeNotification:oldNotifObj];
        [prefx setObject:nil forKey:@"NotificationObject"];
        [self addNotification];
        NSLog(@"remove old notification and add a new one");
    }
}
```

and here's the `addNotification` method

```
-(void)addNotification
{
    //set the notification
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    localNotif.fireDate = self.timePicker.date;
    localNotif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    localNotif.alertBody = @"Hello world!";
    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];

    NSLog(@"localNotif = %@",localNotif);

    //saving notification to prefs    
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setObject:localNotif forKey:@"NotificationObject"];
    [prefs synchronize];
}
```

the `oldNotifObj` always return null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert the values manually in to an NSDictionary and try adding that to userdefaults. That solves this.
I mean you can  convert the items like `localNotif.fireDate`
`localNotif.repeatInterval`
`localNotif.alertBody`
`localNotif.soundName` etc into string objects and set them in to an NSDictionary. So you can save them into the userdefaults.
`

Comment: I need to remove the notification. So I suppose I need the same exact object.

Comment: try to convert the notification object to nsdata using NSKeyedArchiver. you can use like `NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:notif];` to set the data and to get it use  `UILocalNotification *notif = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:(NSData *)[array objectAtIndex:i]];`

Comment: The above given is the method you can use `NSKeyedArchiver`. Please change it according to your code sample before building.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will return null. `NSUserDefaults` reads and writes the defaults using a property list file, so it only can manage property list types: `NSString`,`NSNumber`,`NSData`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`.

All in all, you can't store an `UILocalNotification` in `NSUserDefaults`.